# Can I create embeddable arcgis maps without including dojo in my project?

Tags: maps, arcgis, esri

I want to incorporate arcgis maps as small embeddable maps when dealing and presenting addresses. However, the application is not using Dojo in any way and it seems like the arcgis javascript api is dojo based. Is it possible to incorporate the maps without having to slap parts of Dojo into the project? In a similar way I can embed Google maps for example? If that is not possible I'm afraid it would be a deal breaker for using this product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create maps with leaflet and use arcgis services via plugin http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/   It doesn't have full functionality of esri js API, but can be suitable in many cases.